# Error while launching rs_camera.launch

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS1 on Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to interface the Intel Realsense S300 using Ros realsense packages following the ROS wiki . But after installing everything ,It is giving the following error while launching the file rs_camera.launch from the  realsense2_camera package .

```
[ERROR] [1559802465.767875259]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/realsense2_camera] of type [realsense2_camera/RealSenseNodeFactory] even after refreshing the cache: Could not find library corresponding to plugin realsense2_camera/RealSenseNodeFactory. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
[ERROR] [1559802465.767973735]: The error before refreshing the cache was: Could not find library corresponding to plugin realsense2_camera/RealSenseNodeFactory. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
[FATAL] [1559802465.768221992]: Failed to load nodelet '/camera/realsense2_camera` of type `realsense2_camera/RealSenseNodeFactory` to manager `realsense2_camera_manager'
[camera/realsense2_camera-2] process has died [pid 19480, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet load realsense2_camera/RealSenseNodeFactory realsense2_camera_manager __name:=realsense2_camera __log:=/home/charvi/.ros/log/94b5b2a0-8821-11e9-8a20-bc8556b3e359/camera-realsense2_camera-2.log].
log file: /home/charvi/.ros/log/94b5b2a0-8821-11e9-8a20-bc8556b3e359/camera-realsense2_camera-2*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324790/error-while-launching-rs_camera.launch/) by [charvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/33083/charvi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2019-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Source the folder devel_isolated.

---

Originally posted by [charvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/33083/charvi/) with karma: 50 on 2019-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1